# How to Start with Pjsip Video chat android application?

Tags: android, android-studio, video, chat, pjsip

I have lot of search for tutorial and demo project but i can't find, any one please help me to start learning Pjsip  with guidance and demo app source code thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the official documentation? It literally states: `We have a GUI sample application with video support. The project is located under pjsip-apps/src/vidgui.` [Read more here](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Video_Users_Guide)

I recently build the library for android without any issues, however it did not include the video support. Try and follow the provided steps so you can build their example project and use it as a starting point. Good luck!